# Maintain order of Arraylist in multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I make sure the print out order same as the order in the original array, when two threads are used? I want it printing '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9', but currently the order is not guaranteed. Any way to make it in order? Thank you a lot.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DataStore dataStore = new DataStore();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            dataStore.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        CopyThread t1 = new CopyThread(dataStore);
        CopyThread t2 = new CopyThread(dataStore);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch(Throwable t) {
        }
    }   
}

class CopyThread extends Thread {
    private DataStore data; 

    public CopyThread(DataStore data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void run(){      
        DataStore.Line line = null;
        int lineID;

        while( (line = data.getLine()) != null ){       
            lineID = line.id;       
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + lineID);       
        }   
    }
}

class DataStore {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    int current = 0;

    public synchronized Line getLine () {
        if (current >= lines.size()) {
            return null;
        }
        Line line = new Line(lines.get(current), current);
        current++;

        return line;
    }

    public synchronized void add (String s) {
        lines.add(s);
    }

    public synchronized int size () {
        return lines.size();
    }

    public static class Line {
        public String line;
        public int id;

        public Line (String str, int i) {
            line = str;
            id = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Vector instead of ArrayList .

[Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

> The Vector class implements a growable array of objects. Like an
>   array, it contains components that can be accessed using an integer
>   index. However, the size of a Vector can grow or shrink as needed to
>   accommodate adding and removing items after the Vector has been
>   created.
>
> Each vector tries to optimize storage management by maintaining a
>   capacity and a capacityIncrement. The capacity is always at least as
>   large as the vector size; it is usually larger because as components
>   are added to the vector, the vector's storage increases in chunks the
>   size of capacityIncrement. An application can increase the capacity of
>   a vector before inserting a large number of components; this reduces
>   the amount of incremental reallocation.
>
> The Iterators returned by Vector's iterator and listIterator methods
>   are fail-fast: if the Vector is structurally modified at any time
>   after the Iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   Iterator's own remove or add methods, the Iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the Iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future. The Enumerations returned by Vector's elements method
>   are not fail-fast.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use synchronize to achieve that:

```
synchronized(data) {
  while( (line = data.getLine()) != null ){       
        lineID = line.id;       
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + lineID);       
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested, but then it becomes a single thread program, only one thread is used, if data is synchronized.

Comment: It won't be a single threaded program. You are seeing it because your program doesn't has anything else to do. If you add multiple functionalities and spawn more threads you will see that. Definitely t2 can't do anything since t1 is already holding the lock that's why you are seeing that behaviour.

Comment: But want I want is that t1 & t2 both process the DataStore object, to speed up my application. The while loop would be must more than I shown here. But it is enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Any other way to achieve my concurrent access to the data while keeping the original order in output? Thanks.

Comment: I think wherever you want guaranteed output you have to use synchronize. The idea is to minimize synchronization to as less code as possible. So, if you want only some bit guaranteed put only that bit in synchronization. There is no other way to achieve it.

Comment: Probably multiple threading program is not intended to produce orderly output, which single thread program is designed to do.